# Yajra create a page filtered by a variable

Tags: laravel-10, yajra-datatable

For reasons of quantity of values in the tables I had to switch to work with the serverside to speed up the loading of the tables but now I find myself in difficulty because I can't get the codes I generate to work as before.

I created the tables with the command php artisan datatables:make Tickets, and php artisan datatables:editor Tickets, everything works perfectly now if I create a new table and add

```
(TicketsDataTable)
```

```
public function query(Ticket $model): QueryBuilder { return $model->newQuery() ->whereYear('created_at', '2023') ->whereIn('status', [closed','suspended']); }
```

it works properly. I wanted to do in the controller to create specific tables and I tried to do

```
(TicketsController)
```

```
public function index(TicketsDataTable $dataTable) { $data = DB::table('tickets') ->whereYear('created_at', '2023') ->whereMonth('created_at','01') ->whereIn('status', ['closed]);

     return $dataTable->render('tickets.index',compact('data'));
 }
```

but nothing is filtered the page loads the table with everything and not just with the values I'm looking for, where am I going wrong?

Comment: I need help, someone who knows yajra well, even paid, I need to solve these problems I'm having, I don't understand what I should do. anyone available?